# Inconsistency with link styles of suggested edits on main and meta sites

Tags: bug, design, suggested-edits, per-site-meta

History of the [suggested edits on main](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/history) sites have same style for links to suggested edit itself and to post:

> [image: main]

On [meta sites](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/history) they differ:

> [image: meta]

Comment: There is a disturbing lack of freehand in your images.

Comment: @Won't does this make you nervous?

Comment: Exceedingly, my dear sir.

Comment: This isn't an issue on Graphic Design ([main](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NOKjV.png) vs [meta](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d7IrJ.png)), so this is probably site-specific

Comment: @Cai I can't test most of sites, because history is empty. But Russian SO has the same issue as English SO.

Comment: @Cai after looking to your screenshots I see that Graphic Design hasn't same issue, but has link style issue for posts for BOTH sites. I think link style should be the same for suggested edit and post.